# Return value from timer class

Tags: java, swing, timer

I'm working on a timer-class which I want to use to return a character at a time from a word after a set amount of seconds. Basically I want to display the characters in another class in a JPanel and change the letter I show after a second or so. I can get it to write out the characters in a System.out.println in the same class, but I'm not sure how I'd use it with another class if I only want to return the one character at a time with the time interval. I can't return anything from the run-method as it's void, so any help in how I could solve this would be greatly appreciated.

```
package GU4;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
public class TimerTest {
    Timer timer;
    private String name;
    private int i = 0;
    public TimerTest(int seconds, String name){
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds*1000, 1000);
        this.name = name;

    }
    class RemindTask extends TimerTask{

        public void run() {
            int length = name.length();
            if(i < length){         
            System.out.println(name.charAt(i));
            i++;
            }
            else{
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }

    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TimerTest(2, "Bengt");

}



}
```

Answer (score 6):

Make your class take 1 additional parameter which is a callback for the timer task. Such as:

```
public TimerTest(int seconds, String name, Consumer<String> callback)
```

Then call that callback and pass it the value you would normally want to return.

```
    public void run() {
        int length = name.length();
        if(i < length){
            callback.accept(String.valueOf(name.charAt(i));
            i++;
        } else {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }
```

If your using Java 8 then the `java.util.function.Consumer` class will exist. If your not using java 8 then you can just add your own interface like:

```
public interface Consumer<T> { 
    void accept(T t);
}
```

Putting this all together you would end up with something like: (using java 8)

```
package GU4;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
public class TimerTest {
    Timer timer;
    private String name;
    private int i = 0;
    private Consumer<String> callback;
    public TimerTest(int seconds, String name, Consumer<String> callback) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds*1000, 1000);
        this.name = name;
        this.callback = callback;
    }
    class RemindTask extends TimerTask{

        public void run() {
            int length = name.length();
            if(i < length){
                callback.accept(String.valueOf(name.charAt(i)));
                i++;
            } else {
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TimerTest(2, "Bengt", (c)-> {
            System.out.println("New Val: " + c);
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way might be to use a DelayQueue and have the character drop off the end after the appropriate timeout.

Answer (score -1):

You could include everything the `run()` method does in a separate method in the `RemindTask` class, which will return any type of data you choose, and then call it from inside the `run()` method.